# how to pass data from javascript to winforms user control

Tags: asp.net, javascript

I have a windows user control hosted in IE.

How to pass input from webpage ( probably from javascript ) to  win forms user control?

Comment: a WINDOWS ASP.NET (says your tag) user control in IE? Come again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the [jQuery.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) function.

You can use that to call your ASP.Net page and include request parameters.